# Latex displaying this error missing $ inserted

Tags: latex

```
begin{table}[h]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{c p{5cm} c}\hline
    Attribut & Description & Equation \\ \hline
        $E$ & The set of objects that can't be distinguished from each other based on the available attributes & Let $P \subseteq A$ , 
E(P)  =  \{\ (x, y) \in U^2  : \foralla P, a(x) = a(y) \}\   \\
$ \beta $& Admissible error rate\\
$K$ & Grade level
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

as I'm new to latex, when i use previous code i get this error "missing $ inserted" in the line E(P)  =  {\ (x, y) \in U^2  : \foralla P, a(x) = a(y) }\   \
can anyone help me with this error.

Comment: For future reference, post TeX-related question on [tex.se]. This post isn't really helpful to a wider audience, so there's no real use in migrating it over.

Comment: not helpful for other audience, but helped me

Comment: Yes, you, and I'm referring to a *wider* audience. There is also no `\foralla`.

Comment: don't be anger of me. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are missing an `$` :) The equation `E(P) ...` must be typeset in math mode:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{c p{5cm} c}\hline
    Attribut & Description & Equation \\ \hline
        $E$ & The set of objects that can't be distinguished from each other based on the available attributes & Let $P \subseteq A$ , 
$E(P)  =  \{\ (x, y) \in U^2  : \forall P, a(x) = a(y) \}$ \\
$ \beta $& Admissible error rate\\
$K$ & Grade level
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Also, please make sure you include a complete and compilable document with the minimum of packages and definitions necessary to reproduce the problem.